# Is there a short way to write $(\exists x. f(x)) \implies (\exists x. f(x) \land g(x))$?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Is there a way to simplify $(\exists x. f(x)) \implies (\exists x. f(x) \land g(x))$?

After all, neither $\exists x. f(x) \implies g(x)$ nor $\exists x. f(x) \land g(x)$ are equivalent to this.

Comment: I mean, at first glance it's a statement in the form $(\forall x, P)\lor (\exists x, Q)$, therefore it seems fine for it to have two quantifiers.

Comment: How are you measuring "shortness"? The statement as given has seven "elements" to it: $\exists x$ and $f(x)$ (twice each), $\implies$, $\land$, and $g(x)$. Are you looking for something that only has six elements?

Comment: @BarryCipra Well, $x \implies y$ is a shorter way of writing $\lnot x \lor y$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's equivalent to $$\forall x\neg f(x)\vee\exists x(f(x)\wedge g(x))$$  I don't think there's any way to prettify that.